# Swift4 - UIButton use addTarget in UIView with error

Tags: swift, uibutton

This is code with addTarget in `required init` in UIVIew

```
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    hiddenButton = self.viewWithTag(9000) as? UIButton
    hiddenButton.addTarget(self, action: "hiddenCameraAction:", for: .touchUpInside)
}
```

this is my select function

```
func hiddenCameraAction(_ sender: Any)  {
    //Do something
}
```

when I click the button in `UIView` then application crashes with error :

> TeachSystem[27065:8131674] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[TeachSystem.CameraView hiddenCameraAction:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x121d11050'
>   *** First throw call stack:
>   (0x1ee830ec4 0x1eda01a40 0x1ee749c24 0x21bb74558 0x1ee8367dc 0x1ee83848c 0x21bb48454 0x21b5d5d0c 0x21b5d602c 0x21b5d502c 0x21bb81bac 0x21bb82e10 0x21bb6210c 0x21bc30f68 0x21bc33960 0x21bc2c450 0x1ee7c11f0 0x1ee7c1170 0x1ee7c0a54 0x1ee7bb920 0x1ee7bb1f0 0x1f0a34584 0x21bb46d40 0x105039f40 0x1ee27abb4)
>   libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Question : How to resolve this error?

Answer (score 1):

action should be defined as `#selector`:

```
hiddenButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(hiddenCameraAction(_:)), for: .touchUpInside).
```

Comment: stackoverflow: "Don't forget you can mark this as the accepted answer by clicking its check mark.", it's good to mark your accepted answer

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is to put string into parentheses.

```
action: ("hiddenCameraAction:")
```

... however, this is **deprecated** way how to achieve what you need to achieve.

---

I would recommend you to start using selector which is safer since compiler provides you error immediately and code won't run with bad method name or whatever.

Syntax is: `#selector(method(externalParameter:))`

---

[image]

... you can just start typing and compiler will suggest you what Objective-C method you can put inside

```
action: #selector(hiddenCameraAction(_:))
```

Answer (score 0):

Action should be defined as `#selector` and the function should have an `@objc`
inference.

```
hiddenButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(hiddenCameraAction(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
```

**hiddenCameraAction** function

```
@objc func hiddenCameraAction(_ sender: Any)  {
    //Do something
}
```

The @objc inference allows the hiddenCameraAction method be accessible to the Objective-C runtime.